# Firebase Storage put() method uploads an array of numbers instead of a string

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to upload a string to a Firebase Storage file. I tried it with

```
let myString = '...';
storage.ref('path')
    .child('file.txt')
    .putString(myString, 'raw');
```

and with

```
let myString = '...';
storage.ref('path')
    .child('file.txt')
    .putString(btoa(myString), 'base64');
```

and with

```
let myString = '...';
let array = new TextEncoder("utf-8").encode(myString);
storage.ref('path')
    .child('file.txt')
    .put(myString);
```

but when I download the files via the Firebase Console, they are always encoded as a string representation of an char array. I.e. the text `{"type":"a"}` ends up as

```
123,34,116,121,112,101,34,58,34,97,34,124
```

which is the ASCII representation of

```
{"type":"a"}
```

This is the actual content of the file. Instead of characters, I get a comma-separated list of character codes.

Is that a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:** In case it matters, this happens in Javascript, on React Native / Expo.

Comment: Did you figure out why this is happening?