# Cannot add a base64 image to google cloud storage

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am trying to add a base64 image to google cloud storage. I have tested the base64 string `capturedImage.base64` such that it displays the correct image here: https://jaredwinick.github.io/base64-image-viewer/.

The non-base64 attempt works. So it's not a problem with my firebase setup.:

```
firebase.storage().ref(`...`).putString(capturedImage.base64)
```

the following (each line separately) do not work

```
   firebase.storage().ref(`...`).putString(capturedImage.base64,'base64')
firebase.storage().ref(`...`).putString('data:image/jpg;base64,'+capturedImage.base64,'base64')
firebase.storage().ref(`...`).putString('data:image/jpg;base64,'+capturedImage.base64,'data_url')
```

The error is shown below. Not sure how to debug this.

[image]

Comment: Can you `console.log(capturedImage.base64)` and share the output ?

Comment: It's a little long, but its indeed an image. One thing I noticed is when i do firebase.storage().ref(`...`).putString("test"), the file that is saved is "116,101,115,116". Is that expected behavior?

Comment: Yes it's long but can you please try uploading sample image and share the base66 logged? Also try this: `putString("the_base_64", "base64", { contentType: "image/jpeg" })`

Comment: I tried `.putString("the_base_64", "base64", { contentType: "image/jpeg" })` and the same error occured

Comment: I am unable to replicate the issue. Can you share a screenshot of error logs from terminal (and not app) along with the ref() that you are trying and also base64 string... Which version of Firebase are you using ?

Comment: version 7.9 `[object Object]
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:9:32 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue` apologies for the formatting not sure how to newline

Comment: I did expo install firebase for installation

Comment: That doesn't give any clue from Firebase side. How are you logging the error? It might be best if you share the complete code of that function as it is here in your question.

Comment: firebase.storage().ref(`...`).putString("the_base_64", "base64", { contentType: "image/jpeg" })
                .then(snapshot => {
                  console.log('Uploaded.');
                })
                .catch(err => console.error(err))

Comment: Alright, try logging the error like this `console.log(JSON.stringify(err))` and then share it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236751/discussion-between-david-kong-and-dharmaraj).

Comment: My current suspicion is that it is related to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60602328/firebase-storage-put-method-uploads-an-array-of-numbers-instead-of-a-string